# How do you set the default font for a new text object?

Tags: text-object

Whenever I add a text object it always defaults to *Bfont*. How do I change that? I have not seen any settings in the user preferences. (However there is a setting to change the UI font.)

[image: Font settings]

Comment: Impossible as said in the comment, but you can set the default font path in the user preferences so that it is shorter to change

Comment: I know it's not a good solution, but you can always set a new font and use a Fake User. Everytime you open Blender the new font'll be there.